# STUCK Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade from Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: upgrade

So I'm currently installing Ubuntu 18, and as of now, my Ubuntu interface has already turned to ubuntu 18 interface. However, the upgrade process is still not finish because it is stuck at

```
Checking for installed snaps

Installing snap gnome-3-26-1604
```

Please refer to the image below: [image]

It's been two hours at this point already.

Comment: gnome-3-26-1604 is obsolete in 18.04 and has been replaced by gnome-3-28-1804. I suggest that you ignore the error message and continue with the upgrade. After rebooting remove the gnome-3-26-1604 snap package and replace it with gnome-3-28-1804. That's what I did after upgrading to 18.04. You might also need to run Boot-Repair because grub hasn't been upgraded yet.

Comment: it's not an error message, the installation wont progress. What should i do?

Comment: It's just hanging there @karel

Comment: I would let it run, the release-upgrade can take a long time especially on less powerful hardware, or limited devices (x86 or low ram). I would probably log in to a terminal, and check you have sufficient free space on / too.

Comment: i rebooted it and typed sudo apt-get dist-upgrade --fix-missing at the terminal is this ok? @guiverc

Comment: I would just `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`   (you can `sudo apt-get --fix-missing` if it tells you it's required)

Comment: thank you, i think it's all fixed now. You all deserved 5 stars!!!

Answer (score 0):

you just need to type

```
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Ignore the messages.

Answer found by : @guiverc : [STUCK Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade from Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150952/stuck-ubuntu-18-04-upgrade-from-ubuntu-17-10/1150994#comment1913313_1150952) (guiverc you can make an answer)

Answer (score 0):

gnome-3-26-1604 is obsolete in 18.04 and has been replaced by gnome-3-28-1804. I suggest that you ignore the error message and reboot with `sudo reboot`. After rebooting remove the gnome-3-26-1604 snap package and replace it with gnome-3-28-1804. That's what I did after upgrading to 18.04.